# When you have a server and don't use RVM, do you sudo gem install or just gem install?

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby, phusion-passenger, rubygems

When you set up a Linux server with Ruby on Rails on it, and you're not using RVM, is the best practice to `sudo gem install [gem]` or `gem install [gem]`. I'm using the second approach, and storing my gems in a user `~/.gems` directory and just having Phusion Passenger + Apache look for gems in that directory under the user directory. Is this frowned upon or OK?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any reason not to do that, unless you want the same set of gems to be available to another user on the box (but then you can get into group ownership). Is there some reason you don't want to use rvm?

Comment: On the server I have no reason to use RVM since I only need to run one version of Ruby. In that case I find that using RVM makes things more complicated and less transparent.